# How to get Jenkins Agent disconnection timestamp?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, swarm

I'm trying to retrieve this value here via groovy, in reference from the GUI [image: Node View]

Currently I have a workaround solution by inserting the timestamp into the offline message, and then parsing it out later on.

But I would really like a solution where I would be able to retrieve this date data straight from Jenkins.
I have tried the functions

```
getOfflineCause()
```

and

```
getOfflineCauseReason()
```

Referenced in https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html, but the timestamps werent included in the output. Thanks in advance.

I have a working solution, but I would like to get help with a more robust one.